# Problems with opening a window - Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a simple 2d game with C# using forms but when i run it at 60 fps it uses 50% of my CPU and doesn't use my GPU at all. I've been looking for hours and can't find another way to do it. How do i get it to run on my GPU?

Also I'm using a thread to wait in between frames with `Thread.Sleep(15)`. I don't know if this is a good way to do it.

I was following this video for the window https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnGM1p2vsbE

This is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace RadiantEngine
{
    class Canvas : Form
    {
        public Canvas()
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        }
    }


    public abstract class RadiantWindow
    {
        public Vector2 ScreenSize;
        public string Title;
        private Canvas Window;
        private Thread GameLoopThread;

        public float num;

        Bitmap image = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("F:/VS/RadiantEngine/RadiantEngine/dog.png");

        public RadiantWindow(Vector2 ScreenSize, string Title)
        {
            this.ScreenSize = ScreenSize;

            this.Title = Title;

            EngineInit();
        }

        public RadiantWindow(float x, float y, string Title)
        {
            Vector2 _ScreenSize = new Vector2();
            this.ScreenSize = _ScreenSize;

            this.Title = Title;

            EngineInit();
        }

        void EngineInit()
        {
            Window = new Canvas();

            Window.Text = Title;
            Window.Size = new Size((int)ScreenSize.x, (int)ScreenSize.y);
            Window.Paint += Renderer;


            GameLoopThread = new Thread(GameLoop);
            GameLoopThread.Start();

            Application.Run(Window);
        }


        private void Renderer(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.Clear(Color.Aqua);


            g.DrawImage(RadiantEngine.engine.renderer.FrameRender(), 0, 0);
        }


        void GameLoop()
        {
            OnLoad();
            while (GameLoopThread.IsAlive)
            {
                try
                {
                    OnDraw();

                    Window.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { Window.Refresh(); });
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Game Is Loading");
                }
                Thread.Sleep(15);
            }
        }

        public abstract void OnDraw();
        public abstract void OnLoad();
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: WinForms applications are rendered on the CPU, not the GPU. WPF applications can use DirectX and be rendered on the GPU, though.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is almost never a good idea. Usually people doing that should be using something like a Timer.

Comment: See following : https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/119441/common-features/graphics-performance-and-high-dpi/directx-hardware-acceleration

Comment: Using a thread and BeginInvoke() is not a good idea.  In effect the UI thread is burning 100% core, trying to keep up with the invoke requests but never being able to keep up.  The invoke queue backs up and, eventually, the program crashes with OOM.  But much more noticeably, it now no longer takes care of other lower priority duties, like timers and paint requests.  Use the Timer in the toolbox instead, set the Interval to 15 or 31.   If you set it too low (like 15), it now simply delays the Tick events.

Comment: You're not going to win this battle at 60 fps  (maybe 30 will be passable with WinForms).  Windows Forms just isn't up to high-frame-rate gaming.  WPF, on the other hand can use the [CompositionTarget.Rendering](https://github.com/Microsoft/wpf-samples/tree/master/Visual%20Layer/CompositionTarget) technique.